# Prove the integral $\int_{C_a} f(z) ~e^{iz}~\mathrm{d}z$ converges to $0$ when $a\to\infty$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, improper-integrals, residue-calculus, complex-integration

Let $f(z)$ be a rational function without poles on the real axis. Assume that the degree of the numerator is strictly smaller than the degree of the denominator. Define $C_a$ be the arc $$\{ae^{it};t\in[0,\pi]\}.$$
where $a$ is a postive real number.

I want to know the integral
$$\int_{C_a} f(z)~e^{iz}~\mathrm{d}z$$
converges to $0$ when $a\to \infty$.

---

**update:** my friend told me this is [Jordan's lemma.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%27s_lemma)

---

**[Has been proved to be wrong.]** Alternatively, we need to prove
$$\int_{C_a} f(z)~\mathrm{d}z=\int_{C_a} \frac{p_n(z)}{q_m(z)}~\mathrm{d}z$$
converges to $0$ when $a\to \infty$, where $p_n$ and $q_m$ are the polynomials of degree $n$ and $m$ respectively with $n<m$.

It is derived from an exercise. Following the standard procedure here [Example I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem), I stuck with the proof of the above statement.

> Let $f$ be a rational function without poles on the real axis. Assume that the degree of the numerator is strictly smaller than the degree of the denominator. Show that 
>   $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)e^{ix}~\mathrm{d} x=2\pi i\sum_{\mathrm{Im} z_k>0}\mathrm{res}_{z_k}(f(z)e^{iz})$$
>   where $z_k$ denote the poles of $f$. The sum is over all poles in the upper half plane.

Comment: Is $a>0$? Please tell us.

Comment: @zhw. Thanks for pointing out. I fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Alternatively, we need to prove
>   $$ \int_{C_a} f(z)~\mathrm{d}z=\int_{C_a} \frac{p_n(z)}{q_m(z)}~\mathrm{d}z $$
>   converges to $0$ when $a\to\infty$.

No, this is not true if $n = m-1$. As a simple example, notice that

$$ \lim_{a\to\infty} \int_{C_a} \frac{dz}{z+i} = i\pi. $$

So you cannot drop out the factor $e^{iz}$. To show the convergence, let $a_0 > 0$ be large enough that every pole of $f(z)$ on $\mathbb{C}$ lies inside the circle $|z| = a_0$. Also pick $M > 0$ such that $|f(z)| \leq \frac{M}{|z|^{m-n}}$ for all $|z| > a_0$, Then for all $a > a_0$, we have

$$ \left| \int_{C} f(z)e^{iz} \, dz \right|
= \left| \int_{0}^{\pi} f(a e^{i\theta}) e^{ia e^{i\theta}} \, ia e^{i\theta} d\theta \right| 
\leq \frac{M}{a^{m-n-1}} \int_{0}^{\pi} e^{-a\sin\theta} \, d\theta. $$

Since $e^{-a\sin\theta} $ is uniformly bounded by $1$ and converges pointwise to $0$ for $\theta \in (0, \pi)$ as $a\to\infty$, dominated convergence theorem tells that the integral converges to $0$ as well. A more elementary solution is to utilize the bound $\sin\theta \geq \frac{2}{\pi}\theta$ for $0 \leq \theta\leq\frac{\pi}{2}$:

$$ \int_{0}^{\pi} e^{-a\sin\theta} \, d\theta
= 2\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} e^{-a\sin\theta} \, d\theta
\leq 2\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} e^{-\frac{2a}{\pi}\theta} \, d\theta
\leq \frac{\pi}{a}. $$

Therefore

$$ \left| \int_{C} f(z)e^{iz} \, dz \right| \leq \frac{\pi M}{a^{m-n}} \xrightarrow[a\to\infty]{} 0. $$

Comment: Thank you! And the counter-example is simple and powerful...

Comment: Sorry to bother you again: how to prove there exist $M>0$ and $a_0>0$ such that for $|z|>a_0$,
$$\left|\frac{p^n(z)}{q^m(z)}\right|\leq \frac{M}{|z|^{m-n}}$$ where $p_n$ and $q_m$ are the polynomials of degree $n$ and $m$ respectively with $n<m$. (I open a new question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2448646/to-prove-left-fracpnqm-right-leq-fracmzm-n-for-some-m)