# To prove $\left|\frac{p_n(z)}{q_m(z)}\right|\leq \frac{M}{|z|^{m-n}}$ for some $M>0$

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality

To prove there exist $M>0$ and $a_0>0$ such that for $|z|>a_0$,
$$\left|\frac{p_n(z)}{q_m(z)}\right|\leq \frac{M}{|z|^{m-n}}$$ where $p_n$ and $q_m$ are the polynomials of degree $n$ and $m$ respectively with $n<m$.

I encountered this question in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2448419/prove-the-integral-int-c-a-fz-eiz-mathrmdz-converges-to-0-when).

According to the hint, it is enough to show that for large enough $R$ and for every $|z|>R$, we have
$$\left|\frac{z-z_1}{z-z_2}\right|<M$$
In fact,
$$\left|\frac{z-z_1}{z-z_2}\right|<\frac{|z-z_2|+|z_2-z_1|}{|z-z_2|}=1+\frac{|z_2-z_1|}{|z-z_2|}<M.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $p_n(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_kz^k$, and  $q_n(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{m}b_kz^k$ with $a_n\not=0$ and $b_m\not=0$. 
Note that 
$$\lim_{r\to +\infty }\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\frac{|b_k|}{r^{m-k}}=\lim_{r\to +\infty }\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{|a_k|}{r^{m-k}}=0.$$
Then, for $|z|$ is "sufficiently large",
$$\left|\frac{p_n(z)z^{m-n}}{q_m(z)}\right|\leq \frac{|a_n|+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{|a_k|}{|z|^{m-k}}}{|b_m|-\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\frac{|b_k|}{|z|^{m-k}}}\leq 2\frac{|a_n|}{|b_m|}.$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thank you! I update the post according to your hint.

Comment: @LeoGardon OK, I was editing my answer. I hope that everything is clear now.

Answer (score 1):

This concludes from **Growth Lemma** says for polynomial $p(z)=a_0+\cdots+a_nz^n$ of degree $n$ and $a_n\neq0$ then for enough large $|z|$ we have
$$\dfrac{|a_n|}{2}|z|^n\leq|p(z)|\leq\dfrac{3|a_n|}{2}|z|^n$$
apply this for $p$ and $q$ and find desire bound. you may find a version of Growth Lemma [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=g0KHD7EIl4cC&pg=PA195&lpg=PA195&dq=Growth%20Lemma&source=bl&ots=xOubcB7SrQ&sig=ROZ_t8VfkoQxY35eHWZGYaediVo&hl=fa&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjp6Iqzz8fWAhXCZpoKHXqhBr8Q6AEIXDAI#v=onepage&q=Growth%20Lemma&f=false).

Comment: Could you point to a proof of this lemma?

Comment: @CuriousKid7 I added it's link.